# Python read data from Buffer

Tags: python, buffer

Im a Rookie!

im reading data from a sensor with:

```
data = ""
dev = os.open("/dev/rtlightsensor0", os.0_RDWR)
data = os.read(dev,16)

print(data)
```

result:
b'1 53 -5 1\n'

I was thinking thats a String but seems to be like a Buffer? Could anyone give me a Tip, how to get the 4 Numbers?

i tried

```
value1 = data[1]
```

but the result was a different number..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**After read other's answer, I must make a supplement here.**

I just figured out that you want to read text file instead of binary file, so the codes above won't work for your situation, but I have a better way to read instead of use binary read.

```
file = open("/dev/rtlightsensor0", "r")
line = file.readline()
data = [int(each) for each in line.split())
```

Here I read file as a string instead of bytes because your file is text file. Try it and you will find it's really concise.

**Below is my original answer, if one day you need read binary data, it will work.**

I'm also a Rookie!

You didn't describe your question clearly enough, so I can just guess that you have 4 32-bit(4 bytes) int in your file, which you want to read into your program.

`os.read` is a binary file read function, so the variable `data` you got is `bytes` instead of list of number. Python can't infer the length your number as it can be 4 32-bit number or 1 128-bit number or something else, so you need to say it explicitly by some way.

There is also a little problem that your data is big endian or little endian? If your data doesn't come from network communication, I suppose it's little endian. If you find data is wrong(for example, unbelievable large), you can try to convert 'big' into 'little'.

So you can finish your code like this:

```
dev = os.open("/dev/rtlightsensor0", os.0_RDWR)
raw_data = os.read(dev,16)
data = []
data.append(int.from_bytes(raw_data[0:4], 'little'))
data.append(int.from_bytes(raw_data[4:8], 'little'))
data.append(int.from_bytes(raw_data[8:12], 'little'))
data.append(int.from_bytes(raw_data[12:16], 'little'))
print(data)
```

But **DO NOT** do it like that because it's really silly. If you can understand the code above, then you can write it better like this:

```
dev = os.open("/dev/rtlightsensor0", os.0_RDWR)
raw_data = os.read(dev, 16)
data = [int.from_bytes(raw_data[i * 4: (i + 1) * 4], 'little') for i in range(4)]
print(data)
```

By the way, it's not wise to read binary data like this. Generally speaking, the package `numpy` is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

It is a byte array. You can convert the byte array to string using `decode` function

```
>>> test = b'1 53 -5 1\n'
>>> type(test)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> test[0]
49
>>> test_1 = test.decode("utf-8")
>>> test_1[0]
'1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the integers using a list comprehension:

```
[int(x) for x in b'1 53 -5 1\n'.decode().split(' ')] 
# [1, 53, -5, 1]
```

Comment: thank you very much, your way is much faster then my! :)